# Java Bean Mapper - create using custom method

Tags: java, mapping, dozer, orika

I am trying to map an object of type `A` to type `B`. `B` is a class in one of the library, so i cannot modify it. An instance of type `B` is created by calling a special static method. And then, I call the getters from `A` and set it on `B`.

I want to try this bean mapping functionality using Dozer or Orika. But is there a way to specify that `B` needs to be created by calling this specific create method.

I was going through Dozer's documentation and this is what I found:

```
<mappings>          
  <mapping>
    <class-a>org.dozer.vo.A</class-a>
    <class-b>org.dozer.vo.B</class-b>
    <!-- Any custom field mapping xml would go here -->
  </mapping>
</mappings>
```

Is there a way to specify the custom create method, which would create the instance of `B` ?

Comment: yes its possible.. If you can show the special static method you mentioned I'll try to show how it can be done

Comment: Thanks for the help @Ray